# Search and replace string within all files ending in wp-config.php only

Tags: linux, string

I am trying to search for the string localhost within all wp-config.php files in the home directory of my server and replacing it with myhostname.com without affecting any other files.

here is the seach command i have so far

```
find /home/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/localhost/myhostname.com/g' {} ;
```

Comment: Looks like you need a `-name` predicate (or a shell that supports `**` expansion).  Either way, this is a "how to use find" question, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below.

```
 sed -i 's/string/myhostname.com/g' *wp-config.php
```